# How to avoid checking await inside async in Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, async-await

I would like to use `await` without declaring an `async function` in Webpack. This is supported by [Chromium browsers](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await) and proposed to [ECMAScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) (stage 3).

Right now I'm having this error with Webpack:

```
Module parse failed: Cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function
```

How can I add an exception in Webpack just for that?

Comment: Can you not do `.then` (chain) on the `pending` promise which was returned?

Comment: check: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/9177 5.0.0-alpha.15

Comment: Why "*without declaring an async function*"?

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-top-level-await